# Making a Chess Game with jQuery UI. I have used Draggable, but i need to make them not stack

Tags: jquery

I have made this chess game, but i need help with the accept setting in jQuery UI Droppable.

Here is the fiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/kevinsimper/ZzHjz/3/

I tried to do that, when you drop something, it will update all the td there are empty, but it do not seems to work.

Can you help me?

Comment: Thank you :) I must try a little more, it do not seems that people can answer my question, heh.

Comment: I cannot understand what exactly the problem is. I don't see a problem in the fiddle you've provided. Could you describe your problem more thoroughly?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**The question should probably have stated:**

> After dragging an element, the recently vacated td does not become
>   a valid, droppable, target for future drags.

**The problem was:**
You were only creating droppable objects on the initial set of td:empty. Therefore, any non-empty td did not even have a droppable object created to manipulate.

**The solution is:**
Create droppable objects on all the td's. Then disable droppability on all the non-empty td's. Note that you don't have to enable droppability on all the td:empty's every time. You only have to enable it on the recently vacated td. (You should also disable droppability on the newly occupied td.)

http://jsfiddle.net/pabo/7M3WJ/

```
$('a').draggable({ containment: "table", revert: 'invalid' });

$('td').droppable({
    drop: function(ev, ui) {
        var dropped = ui.draggable;
        var droppedOn = $(this);
        $(droppedOn).droppable("disable");
        $(dropped).parent().droppable("enable");
        $(dropped).detach().css({top: 0, left: 0}).appendTo(droppedOn);
    }
});   

$('td').not('td:empty').droppable("disable");
```

...incidentally, shouldn't a chess board be 8x8, and not 10x10?

Comment: I just spent a good 30 minutes troubleshooting my fiddle only to discover it is not broken at all. using **jquery 1.7.2** instead of **jquery (edge)** works fine. I've updated the fiddle to use 1.7.2.

Answer (score 0):

```
$(document).ready(function(){
        var cls='';

        var x=1;

        for(i=1;i<=64;i++){


             if(x && i%2!=0 ||!x&&i%2==0)
            {

                cls = "white";

            }
        else
        {

            cls="grey";
        }
        var content="<div class='"+cls+"'></div>";
        //alert(i/8)
        if(i/8>1&&i/8<=2||i/8>6&&i/8<=7){

             content="<div class='"+cls+"'><a>&#9817</a></div>";
            }
            if(i/8==0.125||i/8==1||i/8==7.125||i/8==8){

             content="<div class='"+cls+"'><a>&#9814;</a></div>";
            }
            if(i/8==0.25||i/8==0.875||i/8==7.25||i/8==7.875){

             content="<div class='"+cls+"'><a>&#9816;</a></div>";
            }
            if(i/8==0.375||i/8==0.75||i/8==7.375||i/8==7.75){

             content="<div class='"+cls+"'><a>&#9815;</a></div>";
            }
            if(i/8==0.5&&i/8<=2||i/8==7.5&&i/8<=8){

             content="<div class='"+cls+"'><a>&#9813;</a></div>";
            }
            if(i/8==0.625&&i/8<=2||i/8==7.625&&i/8<=8){

             content="<div class='"+cls+"'><a>&#9812;</a></div>";
            }



            $("#board").append(content);
            //$("#board").append("<div class='"+k+"'></div>");
            if(i%8==0)
                x=!x;   
                }
         $('a').draggable();

    $('div').droppable({
        drop: function(ev, ui) {
            var dropped = ui.draggable;
            var droppedOn = $(this);

           $(dropped).detach().css({top: 0, left: 0}).appendTo(droppedOn);
        }
    });   

    $(' div').not(' div:empty').droppable();



    });
```

Comment: chess board using jquery

Comment: Some description of the code would help readers understand your solution.